# Merge files based on first column and add zeros where the column name doesn't match

Tags: command-line, text-processing, join

I have two files:
file 1

```
1   a  
 2   b  
  3   c
```

**file2:**

```
1   d                                                                                     
2   e  
4   f  
5   h
```

Expected output

**file 3**

```
1 a d   
2 b e   
3 c 0    
4 0 f    
5 0 h
```

I tried the `join` command but it seems to blindly join the columns without looking for matching patterns in the first column in two files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would really help if the question had shown the actual command line being used, not to mention the incorrect output.

But I suspect that this is what you want:

```
$ join   -o auto   -e '0'   -a 1   -a 2   -1 1   -2 1   f1   f2
1 a d
2 b e
3 c 0
4 0 f
5 0 h
```